# Add color to transparent image strip

Tags: transparency, video-sequence-editor

I rendered out an image strip with transparent background. I want to add color to the background in the video editing section of blender. Normally what I do is that I add color strip and in compositing set the image strip to alpha over. But somehow the recent rendered footage is not working with this method. I think the new version of blender added a black background to the renders. Is there a way I can make this work without re-rendering all of the footage again.
And if anybody can tell me show to share the blend file here I will share that too

Comment: you can share your blend file by opening https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions. You should - before uploading - go in file -> external data -> pack resources and then save file so that we can "see" your footage.

Comment: Can an image strip be packed into blend file? I have tried packing but it is not working

Comment: Tbh I don’t know…maybe provide your image strip by another cloud service like Dropbox or google?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=5AjPBxzz" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/5AjPBxzz/)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xtdatz4afknf7g4/AACjqg4OmXMr8reKe6u2whm4a?dl=0

Comment: blend file and the drobox link to the animation frames

Comment: sorry, i hoped your first sentence was a fact (I rendered out an image strip with transparent background). But unfortunately your background of your images is not transparent. And i don't think that the VSE is capable of making a background from intransparent to transparent.....

Comment: I did render a transparent strip. I dont know why a black background was added to it . I will share the blend file of the animation. Maybe you can render and check from that

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=DPY4eXDp" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/DPY4eXDp/)

Comment: Can you check the file and tell me if i did something wrong? I did not pack this file as it was getting very heavy. But this file will give you an idea of the situation. Thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130761/discussion-between-muhammad-wajahat-and-chris).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the color format to RGBA (a for alpha)

[image]

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. I never change these settings. Didnt even know their function :)

Comment: You are welcome. I also only know 20% of Blender….

Comment: Please check the checkmark left to my answer….☺️